# Why can't I see tables in SSMS

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I recently created a Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse and used the AdventureWorks sample database.  When try to access the database in SSMS, I can not see any of the database Tables, yet I am able to query them.

Researching on the internet, led me to believe this might be a permission issue, so I right clicked the database, selected Properties | Permission to review the View permission.  However, when I this, I get the following error message:
[image]

I've also upgraded to the latest edition of SSMS, I also dropped and reloaded all the tables making sure I used dbo as the Schema.

As anyone come across this problem and do you have a workaround or fix.

Answer (score 3):

In scripting options, make sure that the engine edition is set as “Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse Edition” and engine type is “Microsoft Azure SQL Database”.

Tools -> Options -> SQL Server OE -> Under General scripting options

Please let us know if this issue persists. We have a fix in the upcoming release for SSMS which will automatically detect the database source to populate these settings.

Thanks!

Comment: Kevin thanks for the reply.  I tried the change, but I'm still not seeing the tables.  I did install SSMS 2017 and I can see my tables in this version of SSMS, but tragically it does not support Script Table as for SQL data warehouse tables. Thanks again.